# To come short of something

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Can I use *to come short* in the following context?

> If we come short of snacks and refreshments, I'll pick up a watermelon.

I know that *to come up short* is used when talking about not meeting standards and expectations. My question is can I use *come (up) short* – notice I left out *up* – in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the verb *come* to *is/are*. For example, I'd say:

> If we **are** short of snacks and refreshments, I'll pick up a watermelon.

NOAD, under its definition for *short*, reads:

> **short of/on** not having enough of (something); lacking or deficient in : *they were short of provisions* | *I know you're short on cash*.

I personally like the version with *on* better:

> If we are short **on** snacks and refreshments, I'll pick up a watermelon.

but clearly both are used.

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-short-on-something) has some good examples under its entry for *be short on something*.